# "Its funny how people see others as themselves" grammatically correct?

Tags: quotes

I just thought of a quotation: "Its funny how people see others as themselves". 
Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: As much as I love grumpy cat, the expectation here is that you give us more information or evidence of the problem you're having. Why do you think it might not be correct? Otherwise it's just proofreading, and grumpy cat certainly would say ***No.*** (And the site agrees with him.)

Comment: Where is the quotation from? And, indeed, is it accurately transcribed in your question, even ignoring the missing apostrophe?

Answer (score 3):

> It's funny how people see others as themselves.

With the addition of an apostrophe, the sentence is correct.
However, I am not sure the sentence means what you (or the author) want it to mean.

As it is written, it states that people look at other people and they think those other people are them. So Alice looks at Bob and she thinks Bob is Alice.

More likely, what is meant is that people have a tendency to project their own (character) traits on the people around them; they think that other people are *like* themselves. So Alice looks at Bob and assumes Bob is *like* Alice.

This is a subtle, but important distinction; I would write the idea down as:

> It's funny how people see others as they see themselves.

Comment: "O wad some Pow'r the Giftie gie us/To see oursels as ithers see us!"